# How to get an outline path from an image in java?

Tags: java

How to get an outline path from an image in java ?
I mean I want to get a a path iterator of the path surrounding the image Ignoring any transparent area in it .

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at open source [Delineate](http://delineate.sourceforge.net/), which is a tool for creating SVG from raster images.

I don't know if it directly supports the "alpha-to-path" feature you need.

If nothing else, it has the pixel-based edge detection and SVG path generation logic in there, which could be hacked to work against alpha if you were suitably motivated.